# Discord Bot | New to coding => Auto-Role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm pretty new to coding. I'm trying to make a discord bot that gives a role when someone joins the discord but it doesn't work and I'm pretty lost right now on what to do.

Here is the code for auto-role when joining the server.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {    
    console.log('User ' + member.user.username + 'has joined the server!') 
    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Members'); 
    member.addRole(role)
});
```

And here's the whole code that I got for the bot (it's not much, right now I only got the bot to turn on).

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"); //Library
const config = require("./config.json"); // config file
const client = new Discord.Client(); //Client creation

client.on('ready', () => { //Bot launched
    console.log(`Launched as a bot: ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User ' + member.user.username + 'has joined the server!') 
    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Members'); 
    member.addRole(role)
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN); //Connect to bot
```

Comment: Can you show the errors you get, or what debugging have you done? Try logging your values and see which do not return as expected

Comment: You are not providing much information to work with, can you provide the current discord.js version you're using and the error(s) you're getting

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to check the box in discord developer portal? Go to your application > bot > scroll down > check server members intent

Answer (score 1):

**First**

`.addRole()` has been deprecated in the latest discord.js version. use this to add a role to member.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    
console.log('User ' + member.user.username + 'has joined the server!') 

let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == 'yourrolenamehere'); 

member.roles.add(role)

});
```

**Second**

Go to [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and enable `Server Members Intent` from `Privileged Gateway Intents` in-order to track changes with members (join, leave, update etc).